# Codeigniter AOP

Tags: php, codeigniter, aop

I need a good implementation of AOP paradigm for Codeigniter PHP Framework.

What do you suggest me?

Comment: hi @manolovn i am trying to implement the same. May i know which is better tutorial to get a clear understanding on codeigniter with AOP ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) is not very widespread in the PHP world yet. I'm not sure CI has any facility for this. Your best bet is likely to [google AOP PHP](http://www.google.de/search?q=aop+php) to find an implementation.

Some libraries (including dead ones)

- https://github.com/goaop/framework
- http://code.google.com/p/phpaspect/
- http://www.aophp.net
- http://www.seasar.org/en/php5/index.html
- http://php-aop.googlecode.com
- http://flow3.typo3.org (as part of their full stack)
- https://github.com/AOP-PHP/AOP

Answer (score 0):

[Exar](http://exarphp.com/) is pretty new, with a focus on performance and only depends on PHP itself.