# AOP realization for PHP

Tags: php, aop

i was searching couple of hours for AOP PHP project. I found some projects, but all of them not finished and not supported. So can you point me to some stable project? Or maybe AOP for some reasons is not so good for PHP? (I used AOP in .net solutions and Java and find it very useful)

Thanks.

Comment: This assumes that you're using object-oriented PHP.  I don't know how aspects make sense outside the context of OOP, but perhaps that's my bias showing.

Comment: Probably you should list the projects you've reviewed for you so far, so it's easier to say if you have missed on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any working Aspect-Oriented PHP libraries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738282/are-there-any-working-aspect-oriented-php-libraries)

Comment: also see my answer here for additional libraries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984570/codeigniter-aop/2984877#2984877

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found some links: see if it useful

**FLOW3**

- http://flow3.typo3.org/documentation/manuals/flow3/flow3.aopframework/
- http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/251-Aspects,-Filters,-and-Signals,-Oh,-My!.html

**Go! AOP Framework**

- https://github.com/goaop/framework

**Lithium**

- http://rad-dev.org/lithium
- http://www.shift8creative.com/blog/aspect-oriented-programming-lithiums-filters

**PHP AOP**

- http://code.google.com/p/php-aop/

**AOP PHP Extension**

- https://github.com/AOP-PHP/AOP