# Best way of approach to learn AOP with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, aop

I have some good knowledge on codeigniter, now i want to learn concepts regarding AOP with codeigniter. I have gone through this tutorial [AOP with Codeigniter](http://www.sitepoint.com/explore-aspect-oriented-programming-with-codeigniter-2/) but i felt little difficult to understand the concepts and terminology.

Can anyone suggest some resources to better understand the concepts?

Many thanks.

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984570/codeigniter-aop